# Escape spaces in file path when executed via bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, filepath

I'm trying to start a java process passing several parameters to it using a bat file. But the problem is that the cmd only jumps and doesn't show anything when using:

```
start cmd/C
```

so making it

```
start cmd/K
```

gives a pop-up cmd where this error is shown

*'C:\New' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

For testing purpose for reproducing the problem you can start a java process by the example below.

I have searched for a solution, but the only thing that is similar to the problem was to use set and after that to work with the parameter. 
set "var=content"

The echo correctly prints the folder with many spaces like: "C:\New Folder and Spaces"
The code is below:

```
SET "currDir=%~dp0" 
echo %currDir% 
start cmd /K "%currDir%"..\jvm\jre\bin\java.exe -version
```

How can I pass the **~dp0** value even it has spaces in it without getting the above mentioned error? What if I should use it several times in a start command like:

```
start cmd /K "%currDir%"..\jvm\jre\bin\java.exe -version -Djava.awt.headless=true %JAVA_OPTIONS% -jar "%~dp0MyJar.jar" -home "%~dp0.." %*
```

Comment: I haven't understand: are you running the command directly from cmd or through a batch file? In cmd, there is no `%~dp0`, there is only `%cd%` which points to the current folder, the current working directory else called. Please clarify that for further help.

Comment: 1. It's a terrible habbit to partially quote paths; always quote them as a whole, like `"%~dp0..\jvm\jre\bin\java.exe"`! 2. `start` may interpret the first quoted string as a window title, so explicitly provide such, like `start "" cmd ...`, to avoid unexpected results. 3. There is no need for an interim variable `%currDir%`, you can use `%~dp0` immediately. 4. Why so you use `cmd /C` or `cmd /K` to run `java.exe`?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when " cmd /K" is removed the execution is ok and the error that next parameter is used as a command does not show anymore.

Answer (score 0):

How about hoping for the existance of short file & folder names, since they never contain white spaces? Try:

```
set currDir=%~sdp0
```

(For more information visit [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)!)

Cheers,
Nikolai